# "init" in Swift's protocols - what for?

Tags: swift, solid-principles, swift-protocols

Could you please explain why one may want to put initializer in Swift's protocol?
I thought that protocols' responsibility is to define what concrete implementation can do, without specyfing implementation details. Isn't initializer such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very contrived example:

```
protocol P {
    init(a: Int)
}

class B: P {
    let a: Int
    required init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }
}

func factory<T: P>(a: Int) -> T {
    return T(a: a)
}

let b: B = factory(a: 1)
```

By allowing the Protocol (`P`) to specify a required initializer, I can write the `factory` function which needs to make new objects.

The init doesn't say what you do with the `Int` that is passed in -- just that it is possible to make `P` concrete values from an Int.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you actually want a protocol to explicitly state that a type supports a particular kind of initializer.  In fact the standard library has several of these and its useful to have some of your own types conform to them.  Check out [ExpressibleByArrayLiteral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) for instance.  This protocol is the reason you can init a `Set` with an array literal like `[1,2,3]`